# Excel formula to fill empty cells in a column with a list from another column/table

Tags: excel-formula

Looking for an excel formula to auto fill only the empty cells of a column with data form another column/table.

The ordered list from table1 was created with the formula:
'=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$11="yes",ROW($A$2:$A$11),""),ROW()-1)-1,1),"")

Then I wanted to distribute the list in to the empty cells of a partially filled column in Table2.
I tried using the formulas:

=IF(F2<>"",F2,C2)

=IF(F2<>"",F2,ROWS(C$2:C2))

=IF(J73<>"",J73,INDEX($C$73:$C$82,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$73:$C$82)-ROW($C$72)/($C$73:$C$82<>""),ROWS(C$73:C73))))

But none of them give me the expected outcome. (see attached image)

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advanced.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1] In "yes list" `C2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(F2="",INDEX(A$2:A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$1:A$10)/(B$2:B$11="yes"),COUNTBLANK(F$2:F2))),"")
```

2] In "Result" `H2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(F2="",C2,F2)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the `IF({1,0}` array-part? Is that `contains value` versus `empty`?

Comment: To avoid `FILTERXML` for non-Windows users your `H2` formula could be replaced with `=CHOOSE(($F$2:$F$11<>"")+1,$C$2:$C$11,$F$2:$F$11)` Office 365 spills the answer. Not sure how it behaves in older Excel.

Comment: @P.b thanks your advice. please see my edited post

Comment: Nice. I come to think of it that in older Excel that would require `=CHOOSE((F2<>"")+1,C2,F2)` and dragged down.

Comment: @P.b Nice, sometimes we think too much.

Comment: @bosco_yip and P.b, thank you so much for your great advice! I use a Mac Excel 2016, does FILTERXML function work in this version?.

Comment: FILTERXML is limited to Windows environment.

Comment: Haha, `IF` is the better option here indeed.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(F2<>"",F2,IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($C$2:$C$11<>"")*ROW($C$2:$C$11),SUMPRODUCT(--(F$2:F2="")))),""))`

In `H2` copied down (I think it requires `ctrl+shift+enter` in older Excel versions).

If value in column F is empty it looks for the Nth appearance op a value in column C. N equals the number of blank cells in column F from start to current row.